# Not able to call a method in AlertController

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, alert, uialertcontroller

**I'm trying to upload a file only if the user clicks on 'Yes', it is not calling the method but**

**new to ionic so I'm not sure if this is right way to call a method in Alert.**

```
 async presentAlertConfirm() {
  const alert = await this.alertController.create({
    header: 'Upload Documents',
    subHeader: 'Do you want to Upload Documents?',
    mode: 'ios',
    backdropDismiss: false,
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'NO',
        role: 'cancel',
        cssClass: 'secondary',
        handler: (blah) => {
          console.log('Confirm Cancel: blah');
          
        }
      }, {
        text: 'YES',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Confirm Yes, yipe')
        // this.changeListener
          this.addImageLan;
          // const el: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('test');
          // el.click();
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  await alert.present();
}
```

> Any help will be useful

Comment: Firstly, in the code you shared, `this.addImageLan` doesn't have parentheses, so it's not a function call.
Secondly, if it still won't call, you should be getting an error in your console which says something like "`addImageLan` is not a function", in which case the issue is the binding of `this`. Is that what you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
this.addImageLan;
```

with

```
this.addImageLan();
```

Comment: I have tried it but it didn't help